# How to end workflow when user delete workflow task?

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I have a document library where we start approval workflow, the approval task is added in the task list.

The issue I am facing is when I delete the task from the list, the workflow still remains in In Progress state. Is there any out of the box way to end the workflow when user delete the task?

Answer (score 0):

## Terminate an In-Process Workflow

You can find the item on which the approval workflow was triggered (that is, the item or document being approved) and view its running workflows ...asuming the item itself has not also been deleted.

From the workflows menu for that item, you can then terminate a running workflow.

## Remove a Workflow from a List

On the other hand, if the item or document no longer exists, the only option is to remove the workflow from the list or library.

You can go to the **workflow settings** page for the list or library that contained the item that was being approved and go to the "**Remove a workflow**" page to stop any in-process workflows of a specific workflow template by selecting the option to remove the workflow.

Be aware that **this will stop all running instances** of the workflow and that you'll need to republish or reattach the workflow to the list before you'll be able to trigger it again on any items.

Comment: These are manual steps which I need to do for each and every time. Is there any automated steps?

Comment: A better approach to preventing the problem may be to change permissions on the task list so that end users cannot delete items there.

Comment: Good suggestion but if user have rights to approve/ reject task then they have rights to delete it too.

Comment: I'll have to double check, but I don't think the "Approve" permission level is necessary to approve tasks; I believe "Approve" is instead used for the publishing/draft security model. I'll confirm and get back to you.